# SQL Server GROUP BY and FIRST

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a lot of gallery objects. I have a lot of pictures. The pictures are in the galleries.

I want to create a view where I list the galleries and some properties of the first picture in the gallery.

Something like:

```
ALTER VIEW [foto].[gallery_with_picture]    
AS 
select
        main.*
        ,FIRST(pics.[picture_id])
        ,FIRST(pics.[picture_width])
        ,FIRST(pics.[picture_height])
        ,FIRST(pics.[URLPart] as picture_url_part)
        ,FIRST(pics.[Extension] as picture_extension)
    from
        [v_gallery] main
        left join [v_picture_recursive] pics on main.[foto_reference_picture_group_modeling_object/obj_id] = pics.woc_root
    group by
        main.*
    order by
        pics.[picture_id]
```

Of course this does not work as SQL Server has no working FIRST aggregate function for this. Or does it?

Or should I do an inner select with a top1 as there is no simpler solution?

Comment: There's no inherent order in SQL tables.  You need to specify how you define the order.

Comment: That is true. I want to get the picture with the smallest id.

Comment: But also I would expect FIRST() to return the first occurence in this particular query before the grouping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
ALTER VIEW [foto].[gallery_with_picture] 
AS
SELECT main.*, /*But best to list columns explicitly*/
       pics.[picture_id],
       pics.[picture_width],
       pics.[picture_height],
       pics.[URLPart]   AS picture_url_part,
       pics.[Extension] AS picture_extension
FROM   [v_gallery] main
       OUTER APPLY
       (SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM   [v_picture_recursive] pics
        WHERE  main.[foto_reference_picture_group_modeling_object/obj_id] =
               pics.woc_root
        ORDER  BY pics.[picture_id]) pics
```

Or another

```
ALTER VIEW [foto].[gallery_with_picture] 
AS
 WITH pics AS ( 
 SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY woc_root 
                               ORDER BY [picture_id]) RN 
 FROM [v_picture_recursive])
SELECT main.*,
       pics.[picture_id],
       pics.[picture_width],
       pics.[picture_height],
       pics.[URLPart]   AS picture_url_part,
       pics.[Extension] AS picture_extension
FROM   [v_gallery] main
       LEFT JOIN pics
         ON main.[foto_reference_picture_group_modeling_object/obj_id] =
            pics.woc_root
            AND RN = 1
```